# How to configure mirror/span port on vSwitch?

Tags: vmware-esx

I have vSphere. And I need to config SPAN/mirror port on vSwitch. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a port group on vlan 4095 on the vswitch and set that port group to promiscous mode.  Add the vm nic that you are going to use to monitor traffic to that port group.